# How to solve Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, validation, conditional-statements, codeigniter-4

I want to make validation for the login activity in Codeigniter 4, the login function is running properly, but there is a problem with the validation. When I try to enter a username that doesn't exist, an error will appear and.says **"Trying to access array offset on value of type null**"

Here's my full code:

```
public function index()
{
    $M_admin = new \App\Models\M_admin();
    $login = $this->request->getPost('login');


    if ($login) {
        $member_username = $this->request->getPost('member_username');
        $member_password = $this->request->getPost('member_password');

        if ($member_username ==  '' or $member_password == '') {
            $err = "Please insert username and password";
        }

        if(empty($err)) {
            $dataMember = $M_admin->where("unm",
            $member_username)->first();
            
            if ($dataMember['unm'] != $member_username
            ){
                $err="Username does not exist";
            }else 
            if ($dataMember['u_p'] != $member_password
            ){
                $err="Incorrect password";
            }
        }
        
        if(empty($err)){
            $dataSesi = [
                'member_id' => $dataMember['id'],
                'member_username' => $dataMember['unm'],
                'member_password' => $dataMember['u_p'],
                ];
                session()->set($dataSesi);
                return redirect()->to('dashboard');
        }

        if ($err) {
            session()->setFlashdata('member_username', $member_username);
            session()->setFlashdata('error', $err);
            return redirect()->to("login");
        }
    }

    return view('v_login');
}
```

and the cause of error are here:

```
 if ($dataMember['unm'] != $member_username
            ){
                $err="Username does not exist";
            }
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
a helpful answer will mean a lot, thanks...

Comment: Have you checked $dataMember['unm'] this data ?

Comment: Hint: Do not use `or`, use. `if ($member_username ==  '' || $member_password == '')` instead.

Comment: @SoftTechnoes
i've try to use f(!empty($dataMember))", and it throw correctly if username doesn;t exist, but because of that, other validation doesn;t work (always return wrong password validation)

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks for the suggestion, ;D.
but it doesn I think, may it affect validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a " firstOrFail " function, you should add a try catch around your code at

```
$dataMember = $M_admin->where("unm",
            $member_username)->first();
```

You probably don't want to do the full check process if an user doesn't exist, you can also add a simple " if(!empty($dataMember))" but adding too much logic in your controller is probably not the best way, at least you should create a private function who do the full checking logic and return " true " or " err = "your_error_message"

I hope my answer can help you. :)

Comment: Thanks in advance for the suggestion!, after I tried to apply "if (empty($dataMember))" before password checking, validation working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if ($dataMember['unm'] != $member_username)` doesn't make sense because you are querying your data based on this value.

```php
$dataMember = $M_admin->where("unm", $member_username)->first();
```

If you get a result from this method, `$dataMember['unm']` has to be equal to `$member_username`.

What you need to do is check if the variable `$dataMember` is empty.

```php
if (empty($dataMember)) {
  $err = "Username does not exist";
} elseif ($dataMember['u_p'] != $member_password) {
  $err = "Incorrect password";
}
```

Comment: Yes, right.
I've added empty error checking before validation like that (and based on the suggestion from the first comment), and now all validation are working properly..

thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I do empty value checking before validation, so the code looks like this

```
if (empty($err)) {
            $dataMember = $M_admin->where("unm", $member_username)->first();
            if (empty($dataMember)) {
                $err = "Invalid Username!";
            } else
            if ($dataMember['u_p'] != SHA1($member_password)) {
                $err = "Incorrect Password1";
            }
        }
```